# MongoDB search for users: filter based on name with regex

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

So, I want to add a search bar to my web application and I want to display the users when I enter names inside my input element.

I filter out the names on the back-end by creating a mongodb query and at the $regex I enter the string that the user entered in the input element (search bar) on the front-end. I thought it was working fine, but now my boss says that many users simply aren't showing up when he enters their name. I went through the entire thing and it has gotta have something to do with the regex I enter in the MongoDb query.

For example when I enter 'jonas' in the search bar I would expect that this would return the document of the user with the `full_name` property value `Jonas Rodrigo`. Am I wrong to think I can simply enter the input element string like I did below? And if so, how can I improve it?

**So this is what it looks like: when I enter the name Jonas I expect this user to show, but unfortunately he doesn't show up.**

[image]

**this is my mongoDB query function: I simply enter the string ('jonas' in this case) into the $regex, but I must be doing something wrong because it doesn't return the desired user (the other two conditions are truthy)**

```
const createUserQuery = (user, query) => User.find({
  $and: [
    { full_name: { $regex: query, $options: 'i' } },
    { _workspace: user._workspace },
    { active: true }
  ]
}).select('profile_pic full_name email created_date');
```

**example mongodb user document**

[image]

Comment: Well, in this case the query will just be the string 'jonas'

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be with your regular expression query.

If you want to search for all names starts with `Jonas`

The value of the `query` parameter you pass to the `createUserQuery` should be like

`^Jonas`

`^` is the key here to get all names start with `Joans`

Comment: Well, Jonas is just an example. I also want users to enter the last name and match that in the full_name property as well.

Comment: @tilly what I am trying to say is you should form your regular expression like that .. that is just an example. As I asked earlier what is the value you are passing for query variable?

Comment: I see. So what I know basically add is the string 'jonas' as the regexp. Basically the string I enter in the input element on the front-end is what I'll end up putting as the regexp

Comment: In this case it will search for the exact string as 'joans'. Adding `^` symbol at start will check for all names starts with joans

Answer (score 0):

As @Mani has said, perhaps it's an issue with your RegEx. You could try something like this expression against your query: `const regex = new RegExp(query, 'g')`.

For example, if `query = Jonas`, the RegEx should match documents with a `full_name` property containing "Jonas Rodrigo".

```
const regex = new RegExp(query, 'g');

const createUserQuery = (user, query) => User.find({
  $and: [
    { full_name: { $regex: regex, $options: 'i' } },
    { _workspace: user._workspace },
    { active: true }
  ]
}).select('profile_pic full_name email created_date');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it